# Conditional update in Amazon local dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I've put following object in Local Dynamo DB.

```
class LicenseEntitilement {

String featureName;       // Primary key
int EntitilementCount;
int UsageCount;
}
```

I need to do conditional update with following expression -

Conditional expression is : (UsageCount + askedCount) < EntitilementCount
askedCount is an Integer.

(UsageCount and EntitlementCount values are in DB and askedCount is local variable.)

Update expression is: UsageCount = UsageCount + askedCount

It's throwing an exception that '+' is not allowed in conditional expression.  Is there any way to achieve this conditional update?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of `ConditionExpression`.

> A condition that must be satisfied in order for a conditional update
>   to succeed.

Look at the below conditional expression. Initially, the item in the table has the following values:-

**`UsageCount` = 1**

**`EntitilementCount` = 5**

Local variable :   `askedCount` = 1 (i.e. increment the value by 1)

```
var params = {
    TableName: "tableName",
    Key: {
        "ID": '3'
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET UsageCount = UsageCount + :askedCount",
    ConditionExpression : "UsageCount < EntitilementCount",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":askedCount": askedCount,
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};
```

I have executed the program 4 times successfully. Fifth time, I have got the `The conditional request failed` error message. This satisfies your requirement.

```
prompt>node updateitem_stock_conditionally.js
Updating the item...
UpdateItem succeeded: {"Attributes":{"UsageCount":2}}

prompt>node updateitem_stock_conditionally.js
Updating the item...
UpdateItem succeeded: {"Attributes":{"UsageCount":3}}

prompt>node updateitem_stock_conditionally.js
Updating the item...
UpdateItem succeeded: {"Attributes":{"UsageCount":4}}

prompt>node updateitem_stock_conditionally.js
Updating the item...
UpdateItem succeeded: {"Attributes":{"UsageCount":5}}

prompt>node updateitem_stock_conditionally.js
Updating the item...
Unable to update item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "The conditional request failed",
  "code": "ConditionalCheckFailedException",
  "time": "2017-04-26T20:29:21.710Z",
  "requestId": "d73571f3-17f3-4aca-a3cf-7f13019a0292",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 0
}
```

Comment: This condition won't help for all cases. In your example, if :askedCount = 3. And if you execute it twice then it allows for 2nd time as well.  To prevent this we need following condition expression – 
(UsageCount + **askedCount**) < EntitilementCount